# How to open a native app like Google Slides with Ionic2 / cordova app

Tags: cordova, ionic2, google-slides

I build an app with Ionic 2 / Angular 2. I have a button open up google slides with inappbrowser. But now I want to open the google slides app instead of inappbrowser (if user have google slides app installed in their phone). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [App-Launcher-Cordova-Plugin](https://github.com/nchutchind/App-Launcher-Cordova-Plugin) to check if Google Slides is installed and if so launch it.

Install it to your project:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/nchutchind/App-Launcher-Cordova-Plugin.git
```

Then use it something like this:

```
var googleSlidesPackageName;
if(device.platform === "Android"){
    googleSlidesPackageName = "com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.slides";
}else if(device.platform === "iOS"){
    googleSlidesPackageName = "com.google.Slides";
}else{
    throw new Error("Don't know the package name for "+device.platform+" platform");
}

window.plugins.launcher.canLaunch({packageName:googleSlidesPackageName}, function(){
    window.plugins.launcher.launch({packageName:googleSlidesPackageName}, successCallback, errorCallback);
}, errorCallback)
```